# Resizing Highchart

Tags: highcharts

What is the recommended way to resize a Highchart that is embedded in an HTML page?

I set the `<div>` that contains the chart (the `chart.options.renderTo`) (and the Highcharts div itself) to `style.resize="both"` but that doesn't seem to take (I suspect because the Highchart URL is in the bottom right of the chart). Specifically I'm looking for the recommended UI cue.

Suggestions?

Comment: [Check the docs](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/design-and-style) and [here's a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/height/).

Comment: can you post some sample code here? to remove highcharts url use this code `credits: {
            enabled: false
        }`

Comment: Super helpful @MarsAndBack thanks! ... hadn't seen this page in the docs, perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set same `padding` on the chart container to see the `resize`. If the chart container dimensions are changed, then you need to call `chart.reflow` method:

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #e2eaad;
    margin: 0 auto;
    resize: both;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

JS:

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }]
});

document.getElementById('container').addEventListener("click", function() {
    chart.reflow();
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pnq8w6tr/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#reflow

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for.